# Looking for Fancy windows forms

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, skinning

Are there any ready made fancy windows forms on top of which I can build my application?

I was able to find only [one working so far](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBkQFjAA&url=http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/FancyNetForms.aspx&ei=ZEHRTdD1FZHzrQex4qHCCg&usg=AFQjCNHX-rpL7zDHjsifLm_pkmGBDmad5g&sig2=7zz7b7VYt7JFcgu2mhT21w)..However,the titlebar and stuff don't maximize on double click and some functionalities of traditional windows forms are missing.

I'm looking for an extended windows forms with good looks.

Do you know any libraries that can help produce good looking windows forms?

Please provide me any links ..

Thank you.

Comment: You keep saying Windows Forms, but have you considered WPF?  That is one of the big perks of WPF.

Comment: We're not familiar with WPF. There's a huge learning curve for it unfortunately

Comment: I understand the issue of learning curve.  However, I picked it up pretty quick and I found that even when I was struggling with things that should be easy, my UI development still happened faster.  That was because I spent less time worrying about exact positioning, anchoring, and resizing.  I can flip controls around, rearrange them, and do a number of different things very quickly.  You may not have time now, but I would encourage you to start looking into WPF.  It will be worth it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Commercial Options**

[Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/) is debatably the best out there right now, and they put a lot of money into supporting the community by sponsoring podcasts.

[DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/) is comparable. They have a lot of skins and I've had good experiences with them in the past.

Both of them have WinForms packages that come in at $799.

[Nevron UI](http://www.nevron.com/Products.UserInterfaceFor.NET.Overview.aspx) ($169) and [DotNetBar](http://www.devcomponents.com/dotnetbar/) ($264) are also options. But you get what you pay for, and some of the free options below are worth looking at before spending money on these.

**Free Options**

[WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx) is Microsoft's next-gen presentation framework, and it is *extremely powerful*. It all the features you're looking for and more, although there is a substantial learning curve.

[Krypton](http://www.componentfactory.com/product?id=3) gets the job done and it's free. It's mature, easy to use, and they continue to updated it. Plus it has a bunch of built-in skins, including some good Office-style skins. I will say that next to WPF it's looking dated. But that goes for most everything.

Comment: DotNetBar is pretty good, and very cost effective compare to some of the other options: http://www.devcomponents.com/dotnetbar/. Nevron UI isn't too bad either: http://www.nevron.com/Products.UserInterfaceFor.NET.Overview.aspx

Comment: @Ira Rainey Thanks Ira, I added them. :)

Answer (score 44):

I know this is probably not the answer that anyone asking this type of question wants to hear, but it's absolutely the answer that they *need* to hear. **The problems with the implementation that you note in your question are *exactly* the kinds of problems that run rampant with this type of thing.**

Any time that you go about changing the look and feel of standard Windows controls (and *especially* something as complicated as forms), you're bound to run into problems. There are all kinds of behaviors that users come to expect because they've been a part of the way Windows works since the very beginning. Some of them are big and obvious, and others are minor and trivial. Trivial, that is, until you try to use them out of habit and find that they don't work.

This is the reason that users get frustrated with things like custom themed or "skinned" applications. Personally, I all but refuse to use them, and I'm not the only I know who feels that way, from power users to grandmothers. They don't help you to work more productively, and in fact, they often hamper exactly that. And it's hardly worth putting up with the compromise because most skins just don't look all that good in the first place, *especially* not to the subjective aesthetic preferences of individual users. For example, you might skin your application in a nice-looking blue color. But what if I *hate* blue with a passion? I'm not going to be very happy when I'm using your app, no matter how beautiful you/your designer think it is. What you call "fancy", others might call anywhere from "distasteful" to downright "ugly".

By *far* the best option is to let the user choose the application's theme. And you don't even need to build a theming system into your application in order to allow for this. Windows has allowed users to customize their system theme since the very beginning. It started out as simply the ability to change the colors used for all on-screen elements, and it's evolved through Windows XP and beyond to a full-fledged theming engine. Stick with it, and resist the urge to tinker. Making your app stick out like a sore thumb is **not** a good thing here. You want to blend in with the rest of the apps on the user's computer. Familiarity translates *directly* to ease-of-use and enhanced user experience. It also means less tech support is required from your company to support your software that you just had to make look different.

You just don't get enough value out of this to justify the problems, limitations, and support nightmares. Focus on making your app *work* better, rather than just *look* better. Users really appreciate that far more, even if they won't admit it. The best changes are the ones that no one ever notices.

Comment: This is a good point. I just want to mention here that there are entire classes of applications that are highly dependant on presentation. Skinning is certainly the type of wheel you shouldn't reinvent, and when dealing with line of business I agree this is bad way to invest your time. But there is a place for skinning, especially in the realm of mass-marketed products. If the argument is that winforms in particular is not well suited to making those types of products... Well, maybe. It can and has been done, although WPF seems like an easier path moving forward.

Comment: @Brian: What sort of market is there where applications have to be skinned to be successful? Remember WinAmp? They released a skinning system and the only people who didn't hate it were 13-year-old kids. The quickly abandoned that and pretended like it never happened by rejiggering all their version numbers. The argument is that it's impossible to do right, regardless of whose wheel you use. Microsoft already created the default platform conventions. Recreating them is going to upset users for little benefit. WPF is quite irrelevant here; it doesn't use the standard Windows API elements.

Comment: Oops, I so much disagree with this answer, if you build a really good skin experience, it has so much advantage and you can easily detect or allow the user to choose the interface they want the first time they start your application, or even go over your heads and detect the current theme they are using. Many programmers just do bland stuff and leave users with un-awesome experiences. And just as an addition, most common beautiful applications out there use very beautiful skins. It shows uniqueness and creativity.

Comment: When creating an end user application you want the users to have a great experience, why not just move back to the 1990's and have websites have the least amount of images on and run windows 3.1. Users now a days are more UX demanding. I totally disagree with your point stated. You can always have a fully functional app with a great looking UI. DevExpress +1

Answer (score 2):

You can use [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Skins/), which has a great selection of skins.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a good library to make your forms look good, I would suggest the Telerik suite for WinForms:

http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms.aspx

They look amazing, even if they are WinForms.

Answer (score 1):

I have used DevExpress for some WinForms projects: http://www.devexpress.com/

It costs $$, but if you absolutely have to use WinForms for your project I have found it to come in very handy the controls are pretty easy to implement and use.

Comment: As you mention DevExpress cost $$ is means its free ? do you have any crack version ?

Answer (score 1):

Finding directly some free library is difficult, you can use System.Drawing class and using its brush classes and 2D object you can make a form of your choice, some sample has been posted on the following url
http://www.csharpkey.com/visualcsharp/gdi/brushes/gradient.htm
http://www.mycutepictures.com/tutorials/csharp/category/general/

or its better you opt for wpf, there you can have ample number of options