# Custom look for C# windows applications

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I'm making C# windows application ("Windows Forms Application") with default components, but I need to change default look of the form and all items on it (buttons, etc.) from classic windows style, to custom. How can I achieve it?

For example make buttons round, add transparency to some objects, make other objects with different shape, and so on.

It doesn't have to be customizable, but I just need to change it from default to something else. Maybe there's some components or something else that I can use? Or maybe there's additional GUI library that I can download and add to the project?

Comment: I'm guessing you're trying to accomplish this in winforms, and not wpf?

Comment: **@Kshitij Mehta**, I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you are asking...

Comment: which framework are you using? Windows Forms or Windows Presentation Foundation?

Comment: I just create new project "Windows Forms Application" in Visual Studio 2010 and that's it...

Comment: Why in the world do you need to do this? The result will look terrible. There's absolutely no reason not to conform to the user's default theme.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looking for Fancy windows forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6019642/looking-for-fancy-windows-forms)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't provide us with many details on how you want to customize the form.

You can change colors used on the form by setting the `BackColor` and `ForeColor` properties.

You can also apply background image to the form and use the `TransparencyKey` property in order to create a form with an irregular shape. More information about this method can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6k15y9et.aspx

Comment: I'm afraid that's not it. I'm sorry that I didn't gave enough information from the start. I edited my question.

Comment: To change the shape of a control, you can use a background image that defines the shape and the look and **TransparencyKey** to define a color that should be transparent (see the link in this answer). Creating custom controls deriving from the default ones can be probably a good solution in this case.

To control the transparency for the form, you can use **Opacity** property.

Comment: So I can set up a transparency key and then use custom images with that color on objects on the form to chenge its shape?

Comment: Suppose you want to create a circullar form in a blue color. If you want to use this method, you have to create a bitmap with a blue circle (that defines the look of the visible part) and pink background (that fills the part that should be invisible). Then you use this as a background image and set **TranparencyKey** to the pink color. It's quite ok to use this for a form, however, as mentioned in another answer, it can be really time consuming to create a nice looking control this way. You can start by looking for an existing controls. See the link posted by Dennis Biondic.

Comment: For for form I understand, but I primarily needed it for components on the form... I guess I have to use custom controls...

Comment: Yes, by creating your own custom controls you can define the look and behaviour by yourself and customize it completely. This is, however, time consuming, so consider looking for ready and free controls first if it's acceptable in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Doing this manually and trying to have something looking nice takes waaay too much time. For start, look at this thread:

[Best Free Controls for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361271/best-free-controls-for-net)